# Как задать в теме WordPress выбор категории при публикации записи?

Tags: wordpress

В теме есть поле, при помощи которого можно публиковать сразу запись, однако в этом поле нет возможности выбора, в какую категорию помещать запись.

[image: скриншот]
тема https://wordpress.com/theme/p2-breathe

**Как создать выпадающий список рубрик?**

Я нашел устаревший [плагин](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/p2-new-post-categories/), но он не работает с моей темой.

Comment: А какая у вас тема, мы должны угадать.

Comment: Есть масса актуальных плагинов для публикации с фронта. А древнюю тему стоит сменить на современную безопасную из оф каталога.

Comment: такие плагины нахожу только платные, а для личного дневника платный плагин слишком шикарно считаю. тема не старая. но она не оф каталога а из каталога wpcom взята была отдельно

Comment: Стоит искать не "в интернетах", а оф каталоге. Их десятки самых разных. И даже формы обратной связи помогут.

Answer (score 0):

Такой плагин вряд ли существует к вашей теме, если у вас премиум тема попросите у их тех поддержки ввести этот код в обновление, если обычная бесплатная тема, то придется самому вставить эту часть кода в тему

Comment: эту это какую часть кода? категорий? мне только вывод категорий нужен

Comment: все зависит от темы, возможно уточните какую тему вы используете